# Add images from folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a file with a bunch of images saved on my computer that I need to use for an app I'm creating. I've searched for how to do this, but most everything leads nowhere. The most promising thing I found was to right click, file path, and click the file I need. This worked up until the last step. Here's some screenshots:
[image: first menu]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[image: second menu]
I need the "CoolCalc" folder, but when clicked nothing happens. Yes, I've tried restarting. I'm so lost on why nothing's working

Comment: You are welcome to drag and drop images into resource directories. Better yet, use the Image Asset wizard (New > Image Asset), if your images are for standard Android icon sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you want to just place images as is with no changing size, just move them into the drawable fodler. You can click Show in Explorer.

2) If you want your images to be used as icon of the app or tabs for example, then Android Studio can auto create different sizes for you. Right click on res, pick new and choose **Image Asset**, then pick image path and give it a name, you can apply some additional changes there.

3) For more sophisticated image addition you can add a plugin such as **Android Drawable Importer**
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658?pr=

**UPD:** "File path" just shows you where your folder/file is located. In your case your drawable folder as seen on your screenshot is located at C:\Users(**your username not in English language, it seems, that's why it bugged**)\AndroidStudioProjects\CoolCalc\app\src\main\res\drawable

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the Show in Explorer button

Comment: @jason-castillo try to go ahead and open My Computer and go to the file path i've written above yourself. Then you can copy your images in here, if you want.

Comment: I can't see the images in the Studio but on the computer they do seem to be there. I'll try to use them to see if they work..

Comment: I can see them when I go to "show image thumbnails"

Comment: YAY they're in there! God bless

Answer (score 0):

If i understood right you have images on a folder and you want to put them in your app right?,  Click in Show in Explorer this will open a the Drawable window then you can move the images

or you can move the folder to your assets

Comment: go to your project folder then click in app/src/main/ here you have two options you create a assets folder or go to res/drawable, i think in your case this will be C:Users/you user name/AndroidStudioProjects/CoolCalc/app/src/main/res/drawable